# Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead

Tags: python, algorithm, list

The problem and my code are below. however, i still get a message saying that "Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead." could anyone explain why my code is not calculating "in-place" please? Thanks!

> Given an array nums, write a function to move all 0's to the end of it while maintaining the relative order of the non-zero elements.
>   For example, given nums = [0, 1, 0, 3, 12], after calling your function, nums should be [1, 3, 12, 0, 0].
>
> Note:
>   You must do this in-place without making a copy of the array.
>   Minimize the total number of operations.

```
class Solution(object):

    def moveZeroes(self, nums):
        count=0
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            if nums[i]==0:
                a=nums.pop(i)                                   
                nums.append(a)
        return nums
```

Comment: It clearly says "Do not return anything", so why do you return something?

Comment: comment `return nums` and change it to `#return nums`

Comment: What gives the message *"Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead."*? Is this some system for assessing your code? How are we supposed to know about that?

Comment: Just delete the return statement and the function will return None, which will count as not 'anything'.  The irony of the statement is that you *did* modify in place, but *not* with the requested minimum of operations.  Each element need only be moved once, and therefore *should* only be moved once.

Answer (score 0):

```
nums = [0, 1, 0, 3, 12]

def moveZeroes(nums):
  pos = 0
  for i in range(len(nums)):
    if nums[i]:
      nums[i], nums[pos] = nums[pos], nums[i]
      pos += 1

moveZeroes(nums)
print(nums)
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 12, 0, 0]
```